# Split Temporary Variable Refactoring Example

Tags: java, variables, split, refactoring, temporary

I'm preparing for my exams and I stumbled across a weird previous year actual exam question:
Perform Split Temporary Variable Refactoring on this piece of code:

```
 public int createUniqueCasenumber (GregorianCalendar date, int departmentID) {
      int temp = 0;

      temp = date.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
      temp = temp * 100;

      temp = temp + date.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
      temp = temp * 100;

      temp = temp + date.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
      temp = temp * 100;

      temp = temp + (date.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * departmentID);

      return temp;
  }
```

Now I understand the Split Temporary Variable Refactoring as a case when a temp variable is used for different purposes and we simply "rename" it into two different making-sense-names.
But in this situation I can't really thinks of smart names, the function of this temp variable is rather similar to a  loop collecting variable.

The only thing remotely close to the required refactoring would be:

```
 public int createUniqueCasenumber (GregorianCalendar date, int departmentID) {
      int result= 0;

      int firstStep = 100 * date.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

      int secondStep = 100 * (firstStep + date.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH));

      int thirdStep = 100 * (secondStep + date.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR));

      result = thirdStep + (date.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * departmentID);

      return result;
  }
```

But why would you do it "in real life" ? Or is there some deep meaning I don't see?
Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Your refactoring is incorrect; each `-step` variable does *not* depend on any of the others (note that each assignment to `temp` from a `date.get` overwrites what was there before).  Also makes it clear that all of the assignments except the last, and all of the multiplications by 100, are useless.

This refactoring makes it clear that these values are independent, and could be assigned in any order (even in parallel, if that were allowed).

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually made a mistake while retyping the method. Every step is dependent on a previous. See correction.
So the question remains, what are the examiners expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor this code in 2 steps

If you look closely, you may notice, that day multyplied by 100 three times, month - twice and year - once

So you can rewrite code in this manner:

```
public int createUniqueCasenumber(GregorianCalendar date, int departmentID) {
    int temp = date.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) * 100 * 100 * 100;

    temp += date.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) * 100 * 100;

    temp += date.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) * 100;

    temp += date.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * departmentID;

    return temp;
}
```

After that it's much easier to split temp variable:

```
public int createUniqueCasenumber(GregorianCalendar date, int departmentID) {
    int magnifiedDay = date.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) * 100 * 100 * 100;

    int magnifiedMonth = date.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) * 100 * 100;

    int magnifiedYear = date.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) * 100;

    int magnifiedHour = date.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * departmentID;

    return magnifiedDay + magnifiedMonth + magnifiedYear + magnifiedHour;
}
```